# How to handle periodic updating of many objects?

Tags: java, coding-style, timer

I am working on a little Java game, leaning on the classic Asteroids.

In this game there are a ton of objects which need to be updated in certain time intervals:

Every frame: Objects that move or rotate.
Every second: The game timer.
Every few seconds: Enemy AI, enemy spawning
Every some-second: Firing a new bullet from the ship weapon.

Currently I'm handling it like this:

```
//This method is called by a timer that is run every 30 milliseconds
//It will iterate through all objects that require periodic updates and call their
//update method every 30ms.
public void frameUpdateLoop(){
    for( Updating u : allObjectsThatNeedPeriodicUpdates ){
        u.update();
    }
}

public class EnemySpawner implements Updating{
    private static final int SPAWN_TRESHOLD=500;
    private int timeUntilNewEnemySpawns=SPAWN_TRESHOLD;

    //This method is called by frameUpdateLoop()
    //It is only supposed to do work once every 500ms, but is called every
    //30ms nonetheless.
    public void update(){
        timeUntilNewEnemySpawns -= 30; //Subtract time since last update
        if( timeUntilNewEnemySpawns <= 0){
            SpawnNewEnemy();
            timeUntilNewEnemySpawns = SPAWN_TRESHOLD;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this is only an example of how I am using it, so I removed the unnecessary parts.

My question is: 
*Is that the right (=a good way) of implementing such an update system?*
When reading around I noticed that most of the time a Timer is used for such a task.

But that would require me to have dozens of timers running at once (one for each object that requires updating). 
If I understand correctly each instance of a Timer also creates a new thread, so I fear that this could become a problem at some point (thread-handling performance loss outweights my current system - or the number of threads becomes too large).

I'm sort of new to Java so I don't know if my fears are baseless or if it really is a bad idea to have so many Timers.

Thank you very much for suggestions, tips and corrections on this topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like your design with `Updating` interface abstracting the details of what actually has to be updated. Of course your current implementation isn't very elegant. Maybe you should create several methods like `updateEveryFrame()`, `updateEverySecond()`, etc.? Each object implements only the methods that it needs to work, leaving others us no-ops.

`Timer` is actually a good choice here [as well](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> This class scales to large numbers of concurrently scheduled tasks (thousands should present no problem)

However I would recommend splitting `allObjectsThatNeedPeriodicUpdates` into: `allObjectsThatNeedUpdateEveryFrame`, `allObjectsThatNeedUpdateEverySecond`, etc. Create one periodic task for first collection, another (with different interval) for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your method looks fine, it's what Half-Life does. The only difference is that Half-Life (and many others including yours truly) send a Delta Time to the update function so that you don't have to hard-code 30ms into every update function. So:

```
public void update(int deltaTime){
    timeUntilNewEnemySpawns -= deltaTime; //Subtract the delta time
    if( timeUntilNewEnemySpawns <= 0){
        SpawnNewEnemy();
        timeUntilNewEnemySpawns = SPAWN_TRESHOLD;
    }
}
```

Using a delta time like this would allow you to change the update interval if you ever wanted/needed to. And yes, you can and will have a bunch of counters that will be keeping track of various in-game events.

I might also change `deltaTime` and `timeUntilNewEnemySpawns` to the java equivalent of a `TimeSpan` so that you can access some useful methods like TotalSeconds and such. That's not required though.

Comment: It's also a good idea to pass a deltaTime because the frame render may take variable milliseconds to complete, and your physics equations need to know how much time has passed. In a slow period, let them take longer jumps, etc.

Comment: @Karl, That's true in a lot of cases, but there's a large discussion about fixed vs variable timesteps that is worth a read here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step